# How old does one generally need to be to reach the healer status in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

Obviously if one gets an E on the required N.E.W.T.S. then you'll go to Mungo's to train, but how long does it take to get to become a healer?

Comment: The top answer on the duplicate question states (very elegantly and in lots of words) that we don't know.

Comment: @Valorum Not an exact duplicate as such as this is specifically about the length of training/age of Healers. Though admittedly very similar.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Your answer is also a very elegant "We don't know" and possibly worthy of transferring to the dupe

Comment: Maybe. My answer focuses on age, alwxwchan's on the training process (albeit using the same sources). I think they're separate but related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's unclear.

There's no canon source that puts a definitive number on it, as far as I'm aware. The recruitment materials seem to focus on the admission requirements rather than the length of training.

> "Well, I don't fancy Healing," said Ron on the last evening of the holidays. He was immersed in a leaflet that carried the crossed bone-and-wand emblem of St Mungo's on its front. "It says here you need at least "E" at N.E.W.T. level in Potions, Herbology, Transfiguration, Charms and Defence Against the Dark Arts. I mean...blimey...don't want much, do they?"
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 29, Careers Advice)*.</sub>

It is true that there's a period of post-Hogwarts training that's required before you can attain the rank of Healer. During this training you are called a Trainee Healer.

> *'Dangerous' Dai Llewellyn Ward: Serious Bites.* Underneath this was a card in a brass holder on which had been handwritten: *Healer-in-Charge: Hippocrates Smethwyck. **Trainee Healer**: Augustus Pye.*
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 22, St Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries)*.</sub>

We know that Trainee Healers can be pretty young.

> "Well - now don't get upset, Molly, but Augustus Pye had an idea...he's the Trainee Healer, you know, **lovely young chap** and very interested in...um...complementary medicine...
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 23, Christmas on the Closed Ward)*.</sub>

That's really all the information we have on the subject. Judging by Pye, you can become a Trainee Healer at a very young age - probably straight out of Hogwarts if you have the right grades. You then learn on the job under the guidance of a more experienced Healer. There's no detail given about how you earn your stripes or how long it takes to become a full Healer.

Comment: For the record, men and women *of a certain age* will refer to any man under the age of abut twenty-eight as young.

Comment: @Valorum True but at least 'young' narrows it down *somewhat*.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! i read the other article, but didn't really give me what i wanted!